# Migrate VMware instances to cloudstack

Tags: vmware, citrix, xen

How can I migrate VMs from a vmware environment to cloudstack on Xen server while retaining the IP information?

Comment: Can anyone chime in on this one?

Comment: If you are talking about a cold/offline migration, Mark's answer is correct. Even then, there may be some guest-OS-specific issues with retaining the network configs that require manual correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can import ova from vcenter and convert it to vhd format.Once converted the put this vhd in any web server ,so it could be downloded through web browser.Login in cloudstack ,go to global settings and find secstorage.allowed.internal.sites and add the web server ip to this value.restart the management server .Again login in cloudsatck ,go to templates ,click on register template.Fill the form ,select hypervisor as xen server ,in url section give the fill url of vhd file ,select the os type ,select the public and featured. and submit

Answer (score 0):

For converting from vmware to xen, I followed these instructions in the past and they worked - 
http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151210&tstart=0.

I haven't played too much with Cloudstack but there's migration information in the latest admin guide (just released this week) and some commentary on VMware migration -  http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX133299.